# How to generate .rej file when git apply a patch

Tags: git

I run git apply patch.diff.
As the result shows, I have a lot of hunks failed.

I saw a lot of discussion about inspecting .rej files in this situation. 
However i do not know where is my .rej file, how can I generate one?

```
Applying patch web/app/views/map.js with 19 rejects...
Rejected hunk #1.
Rejected hunk #2.
Rejected hunk #3.
Rejected hunk #4.
Rejected hunk #5.
Rejected hunk #6.
.....
```

Comment: Use the `--reject` flag.

Comment: hi, I used the flag, but where can I find my .ref file?

Comment: They should be in the directory where the file in question is. Or, you could try `find . -name "*.rej"`.

Comment: Thanks, fund them, just in directories of each rejected files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate them using the `--reject` flag.
You'll find them in the directory where each file in question is.

Comment: So, here's a follow-on question: what does `patch` do if there need to be *many* reject-files?  I'm going to be applying about 300 patches in a loop and I expect there to be many rejects. My other option is to use "--merge" to produce <<<...>>> sequences, but there I'm concerned about those inclusions causing subsequent patches to fail.  Does it overwrite the reject-file? Does it append to it?  What *does* `patch` do??